# Java: Rename a file inside a .jar

Tags: java, file, jar

Usually to rename a file I use:

```
File oldFile = new File("file path");
oldFile.renameTo(new File("file path with new name"));
```

But what if the file I want to rename is inside a .jar executable is there a way to rename it from there?

Comment: This sounds mad. Do you have any background as to why you need to do this?

Comment: I'm a little confused, do you mean rename the .jar file within the same .jar file?

Comment: Apparantly WinZip and WinRar are capable of performing this operation without extracting / re-compressing, so technically speaking I believe it is doable. The standard API (ZipFile, ZipEntry) does not seem to support it however.

Comment: Sean Kenny  no I mean rename a class file inside the jar file

Comment: @aioobe I believe WinZip and WinRar do so by extracting the file to a temporary location first and then automatically repackaging the file later.

Comment: matt bruns  I play a game called java game called Minecraft this game has many Modifications to it produced by the public people. These modifications involve copying class files and putting them inside the game's .jar file I was wondering whether these class files could actually be hidden exe (malware) files with their file names renamed to .class files instead of .exe Since if so I would be more careful as to what modifications I download from the internet. This is actually a research I am currently working on "the posiblity of malware being inside game modifications" minecraft experiment

Comment: [These forum posts](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080605063232AAuEIoD) claim differently.

Comment: ^^@user1546022 If an .exe is renamed to a .class, all you have is a big piece of junk.

Comment: but cant that .class then be renamed back to .exe and then run?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that unless you extract the JAR file, rename the file and repackage it.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a jar, one entry at a time, renaming the entry you want to change. This might be more efficient than unpacking, renaming and repacking.

You cannot rename a class file without changing all the references to that name. Without recompiling all the code, you can use a library like ObjectWebs ASM to inspect the byte code and change references to that class. If the class is referenced in a String, you may want to change the string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may rename a file within a jar. For example you may use [JarEntryFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntryFilter.html)

like this:

```
...
import org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntryData;
import org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntryFilter;
import org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile;
import org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.JarWriter;
import org.springframework.boot.loader.util.AsciiBytes;
...
    JarWriter writer = new JarWriter(destination);
    try {
        JarFile filteredJarFile = sourceJar.getFilteredJarFile(new JarEntryFilter() {
            @Override
            public AsciiBytes apply(AsciiBytes name, JarEntryData entryData) {
                String string = name.toString();
                String exp = "^a.*";
                if (string.matches(exp)) {
                    string = string.replaceFirst(exp, "replaced");
                    return new AsciiBytes(string);
                }
                return name;
            }
        });
        writer.writeEntries(filteredJarFile);
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```